# how can i use perf to profile my code?

Tags: c++, linux, performance, profiling

I'm trying to use "perf" to see what's using all the CPU in my C++ program on Linux.    I want to attach to a running process and get a list of symbols or line numbers that I can then go look at to optimize.

Comment: run your code in one terminal and run `perf top` in another, you'll get the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To attach to a process and see live updates of hotspots:

```
perf top -p $(pidof yourapp)
```

To attach to a process, then analyse it for later evaluation, do:

```
perf record -p $(pidof yourapp)
```

And later:

```
perf report
```

For both, top and record, you can add `--call-graph dwarf` for dwarf-based callgraphs.

Note that you should compile your application with something like `-O2 -g` to get optimizations and debug symbols, otherwise you won't know functions names, files, line numbers etc. pp.